# Offset vs Where performance for pagination with index

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, postgresql-performance, btree

Suppose that you have a list of millions of items, each one with a timestamp (`created_at`).

You also have an index on `created_at DESC`.

Sometimes you need to navigate through *all* items, chronologically, and obviously you will use pagination on `created_at`.

Now I have a question about pagination on big data: considering that there's an index, and no other filter conditions on items, **is there any performance difference in using `OFFSET` or using `WHERE created_at > last_item_timestamp`?**

I mean, **is there any difference in the way that the btree index will be accessed?** Is there any difference in the amount of data that will be loaded from disk?

I ask this because I would say that there's no difference in the traversal of the btree, using OFFSET or WHERE, but from some quick tests that I have made it seems to be a performance difference. In particular I am testing this with PostgreSQL 11.

**Update**: after more reasoning I think that there's actually a difference in the number of tree nodes that have to be read. In case of `OFFSET` you need to read all the N nodes before the item, while with `WHERE` you only need to read log(N) nodes (because you don't need to count them).

Comment: Have you considered comparing the two queries' execution plans?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a performance difference, especially with big `OFFSET`s. With `OFFSET` you `ORDER BY` your indexed column, and then limit the result set by removing the first x rows indicated by `OFFSET x`. All the rows still have to be read from disk.

With `WHERE` you `ORDER BY` your indexed column, but then only read the range of rows specified by your indexed WHERE condition from disk.

For more details, see: [We need tool support for keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) (On the *Use The Index, Luke* blog)

Comment: "All the rows still have to be read from disk": **do you mean the whole rows from table or just the nodes that represent the row inside the btree index?** It seems meaningless to fetch the whole rows from disk if you have do discard them (I have also added an Update to my question above)

Comment: The row has to be fetched from the table, because PostgreSQL's architecture has a concept of "visibility". The information if a row is visible or not is not stored in the index, only in the table. So you need to access the table just to count the rows. But even without that, `OFFSET` loses if you have to scan a big part of the index.

Comment: I have made some more tests: *800k* buffers read if you `SELECT * ... OFFSET`, *170k* buffers read if you `SELECT created_at ... OFFSET`, while only *1k* buffers read, for the same result, if you `SELECT *  ... WHERE`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So even a `COUNT` (e.g. on a `created_at` range) would still require access to the table to check "visibility" of each row? Or is there any shortcut in that case?

Comment: There is a shortcut, the *visibility map*. If a block is marked "all visible" there, the index scan can skip the check. You need a recently vacuumed table for that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, interesting! Can't the same *visibility map* be used for `OFFSET`? (in order to skip the first N rows without reading them from table)

Comment: Yes, but as I said, you would still lose because you have to scan a lot of the index.